# Routing a nested controller - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I have a sub-controller called `visits` and a super called `Subscriber` I'm new to rails and I haven't tackled this concept before so now when I'm trying to render a view for the visits controller I'm getting this error - No route matches [GET] "/subscribers/visits/new" - I'm not sure how to route this convention out? I'll show my code for clarity.

ROUTES:

```
  devise_for :users
  resources :subscribers do
   resources :visits, shallow: true
  end
```

This is not working by the way.

CONTROLLERS

```
  class Subscribers::VisitsController < ApplicationController
   def new
    @subscriber = Subscriber.new
   end

   def create
    @subscriber =  Subscriber.find_by_phone_number(params[:phone_number])
   if @subscriber
    @subscriber.visit += 1
    @subscriber.save
   end
   end
   end

    class SubscribersController < ApplicationController
     def index
      @subscriber = Subscriber.all
     end

     def new
      @subscriber = Subscriber.new
     end

     def create
       @subscriber = Subscriber.create(subscriber_params)
        if @subscriber.save
        flash[:success] = "Subscriber Has Been successfully Created"
        redirect_to new_subscriber_path(:subscriber)
         else
          render "new"
         end
        end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what `rake routes` looks like for you, not sure what the issue is, so I'll just post the solution.

Put the following in your config/routes.rb

```
get '/subscribers/visits/new', to: 'subscribers/visits#new'
```